# Удалённое подключение к MySQL [Ubuntu VPS]

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, vps, облако

Использую бесплатный VPS от Oracle, установлена система Ubuntu.
Установил MySQL-сервер, сделал все настройки по инструкции, но всё-равно не получается удалённо подключиться к серверу. В качестве хоста передаю IP-адрес экземпляра Linux.

Настройки mysql:

- добавил пользователя со всеми правами на 'localhost' и '%'
- заменил локальный адрес в /conf/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf на 0.0.0.0
- разрешил доступ к порту 3306 в брандмауэре
- неоднократно перезапускал сервер mysql

Команда **nmap**  показывает единственный порт 22 (ssh соединение). Это означает, что порт 3306 недоступен, и из-за этого не работает удалённое подключение?

Comment: `telnet IP-адрес-сервера 3306` с той машины, с которой подключаетесь. Должно вывестисть `Trying ... Connected to ... Escape character is '^]'`. Если не вывелось - порт закрыт. Скорее всего блочит бесплатный VPS, пишите в поддержку.

Comment: Спасибо! Подтвердилась проблема с портом.     
"Сети->Виртуальные облачные сети->vcn-...->Сведения о списках безопасности", по данному пути в Oracle Cloud можно добавить правила для портов.